# Why has 20% of my pumpkin plant suddenly died and how can I save it?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, bugs, pumpkins

So I had a thriving Pumpkin plant.  For about a couple of weeks the big leaves in the middle of the plant (so the oldest leaves) started to yellow and get crisply on the edges.  We've had 90 to 100 degree heat and it gets direct sunlight most of the day so I figured it was just stressed.  We turn the hose on it every day during the heat of the day and soak the ground.

I've got grass clippings covering most of the ground.  which is great for keeping most weeds out and keeping the ground from drying out to quickly but I have had to spread a bunch of seven dust to keep controls the bugs  that also love the grass clippings.  But I haven't spread any seven dust for at least three weeks.

**Here are  pictures when it first started to yellow:** 
[image]

[image]

**This is about 4 days ago.**

[image]

And these are from today. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

One of the long vines shriveled up completely by day 4.  The rest of the vines keep growing longer and even have some pumpkins larger than a fist growing on them.   But their leaves closest to the center are starting to yellow too.

What's going on and how can I save my pumpkins!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Do you mean you used Sevin?  This as well as Rotenone is what is killing our bees.  They try to do their thing and get pollen and Sevin on their legs and just that little bit of dust KILLS THE ENTIRE hive.  Have you fertilized at all?

Comment: You have pronounced evidence of fungus.  Glad to hear you water during the day.  this allows the water to evaporate and droplets with spores to dry up before infection can happen.  That is botrytis in the middle of your patch.  Very normal but it means you've too much shade (west side of your home) probably minimal air flow, little to no chemistry for photosynthesis...too much water.  Never ever use Sevin or any pesticide. This is why we are losing our bees.  When we lose our bees, we humans will die within the next year because we won't have our basic most important pollinators.

Comment: @stormy I totally feel you about the bees.  The problem is  I planted three pumpkin shoots two where eaten completely, not a trace left, with  in 24 hours.  If I hadn't used the seven dust the third would have been eaten too.  What could I do  instead of seven?

Comment: @stormy  about the fungus,  could it be I'm giving the plants too much water?

Comment: If your plants were eaten then that was probably due to rodents.  I am unbelieving that Sevin is allowed for homeowner use or even professionals.  It is the worst pesticide, so easy for bees to pick up on their sticky legs take it back to the hive and it kills the entire hive.  Yes, you are giving them too much water. Your soil is compacted probably lots of clay and stays wet a long time.  Next year we can help you find a better spot, prepare the soil better, fertilize correctly.  It really isn't hard when you know the basics.  Just know you should never ever need to use pesticides.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why just in one day my best vines leaves all wilted from one end to the other? One plant of 8 only showing this. The rest are doing well and still growing. I have a 78 incher and wonder if it will still grow. I buried the end of the vine. The vine has only supported one pumpkin and I wonder if it will still grow. Will measure in a couple days again. Bummed out.

Comment: @user23665 Same thing happened to me. and then it started to spread to other vines.   I'm going to get a lot of hate for this, but a lady in my neighborhood told me to spray the stalks with Sevin (pesticide)   so I did.  And the damage has stopped. I was careful to try and avoid getting the flowers (Don't want to hurt the bees).  But I had to get rid of those blasted squash bugs.   Next year I plan on using Neem oil and diatomaceous earth for pest control.  I don't know if it will be as effective but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yellowing of leaves can be caused by nutrient deficiencies and bugs.  Check carefully for [squash bugs](https://extension.umn.edu/yard-and-garden-insects/squash-bugs), and try giving some balanced NPK to your plant.

Comment: Squash bugs were what came immediately to mind. Nasty critters and not obvious until damage is apparent.

Comment: Check for vine borers. You can cut open the vine lengthwise to look for them and kill them. They will affect one vine while the rest are good.